# phpmyadmin access denied on xampp

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm having an error when accessing phpmyadmin

"Cannot connect: invalid settings"

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';
```

I tried all of the similar questions on stackoverflow but it didn't help.

[image]

My last option is to reinstall xampp.

Comment: Hi, could you please edit your question and paste the error messages as text instead of image? If someone googles for the same error they won't be able to find it (google doesn't look for text in images)

Comment: Hi, I had modified the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had fixed the issue thanks to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzs9Z12OTE4

To fix the issue, you need to open xampp control panel then open my.ini under MySQL Config.

Then I added "skip-grant-tables" below [mysqld]